# ISO 8583 parser for .net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, iso8583

I need to send transaction data to TCP port in ISO 8583.
OpenISO8583.net is great tool for .net framework and Jpos for java.

I need to build it in .net core. When installing OpenISO8583.net library in .net core project I get warning. I did lot of digging on the net but not able to find good library for .net core for ISO 8583 support. Please suggest.

> Package 'OpenIso8583.Net 0.5.2' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

[OpenISO8583.net](https://bitbucket.org/openisoj/openiso8583.net/src/master/)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use that particular tool with .NET Core / .NET 5 etc, you - or the maintainer - would need to update it to multi-target those frameworks. Since this hasn't already done, I'm guessing the maintainer had moved on to other things, so this probably means "you" (after checking the license etc; warning: no source I can find cites a license, so there may be legal/compliance issues using it at all).

It might also be [this on GitHub](https://github.com/kamaroly/openiso8583), if that makes forking it easier. You cannot use a .NET Framework library from a .NET Core / .NET 5 application. It is *probably* very little work - quite possibly just a csproj conversion, so: maybe an hour.

If you don't want to do that work (or pay someone to), then you would need to find a different tool for the job. Stack Overflow is explicitly not targeted at library recommendations.